# Adding hashing with resumable.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, resumablejs

I am trying to append hashing with resumable.JS , hooking "fileAdded" event.
How can we append hash with each chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. By Hooking FileAdded Event as below.

   ```
        r.on('fileAdded', function computeHashes(resumableFile, offset, fileReader) {
           //  debugger;
            // var round = resumableFile.resumableObj.getOpt('forceChunkSize') ? Math.ceil : Math.floor;
             var chunkSize = resumableFile.resumableObj.opts.chunkSize;// resumableFile.getOpt('chunkSize');
             var numChunks = Math.max(Math.floor(resumableFile.file.size / chunkSize), 1);
             var forceChunkSize = false;//resumableFile.getOpt('forceChunkSize');
             var startByte, endByte; var hasher = new SparkMD5();
             var func = (resumableFile.file.slice ? 'slice' : (resumableFile.file.mozSlice ? 'mozSlice' : (resumableFile.file.webkitSlice ? 'webkitSlice' : 'slice')));
             var bytes;

             resumableFile.hashes = resumableFile.hashes || [];
             fileReader = fileReader || new FileReader();
             offset = offset || 0;

            // if (resumableFile.resumableObj.cancelled === false) {
                 startByte = offset * chunkSize;
                 endByte = Math.min(resumableFile.file.size, (offset + 1) * chunkSize);

                 if (resumableFile.file.size - endByte < chunkSize && !forceChunkSize) {
                     endByte = resumableFile.file.size;
                 }
                 bytes  = resumableFile.file[func](startByte, endByte);

                 fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
                 // debugger;
                  var spark = SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer.hash(e.target.result);//hasher.append(e.target.result).end();//
                     //console.log(spark);
                     resumableFile.hashes.push(spark);

                     if (numChunks > offset + 1) {
                         computeHashes(resumableFile, offset + 1, fileReader);
                     }
                     if (numChunks == offset + 1) {
                         r.upload();
                     }

                     resumableFile.resumableObj.opts.query = function (resumableFile, resumableObj) {
                        // debugger;
                         return { 'checksum': resumableFile.hashes[resumableObj] };
                     };

                 };

                 fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(bytes);



             // Show progress pabr
             $('.resumable-progress, .resumable-list').show();
             // Show pause, hide resume
             $('.resumable-progress .progress-resume-link').hide();
             $('.resumable-progress .progress-pause-link').show();
             // Add the file to the list
             $('.resumable-list').append('<li class="resumable-file-' + resumableFile.uniqueIdentifier + '">Uploading <span class="resumable-file-name"></span> <span class="resumable-file-progress"></span>');
             $('.resumable-file-' + resumableFile.uniqueIdentifier + ' .resumable-file-name').html(resumableFile.fileName);
             // Actually start the upload

         });
   ```
2. Changing var query to

`(typeof $.resumableObj.opts.query == "function") ? $.resumableObj.opts.query($.fileObj, offset) : $.resumableObj.opts.query;`

so that it returns current Offset/

Comment: I don´t undertstant the second step "Changing var query to". Can you help me?

Comment: 2nd step is used to store the Hash value in resumableObj.opts.query.... you can also change resumable.js and add hashing when params are created